# VS Code with webpack starter kit, Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404

Tags: visual-studio-code

I'm student learning web development, building a basic website with VS code and and webpack starter kit cloned from github.

I'm running a local web server that allows me to see updates to my website at localhost:8080

I am trying to put an image on my website with this code:

img src="src/images/logos/image.jpg" alt="Image"

BTW I know I'm missing the opening and closing tags but when I put those in the code disappears for some reason.

When I run the website with Chrome I don't see the image. In the debugging console in VS Code I get this message:

Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) [http://localhost:8080/src/images/logos/image.jpg]

My question then is how do I get VS Code instead of looking in localhost:8080 to look in the directory that my website actually sits in for the media files? Please let me know if you need any more information. Help is really appreciated.

Comment: BTW I used the absolute path to the image as well and it didn't work.

Comment: Please see https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help and edit your code and text. This might also be of interest: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

I have found the answer to my own question. I needed to put my media in the "dist" folder instead of the "src" folder. Now the images show up.